# Fullcalendar businessHours for specific date per resource

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I want to set businessHours for specific Date. Thus, what I did is passing speicific endDate and startDate to businessHours via php. However, it is not working. All the other businessHours that is with start, end, and dow is working, but only businessHours that is with specific Date is not working. My json Array is like this

```
{
    "title": "A",
    "id": "A",
    "eventColor": "green",
    "businessHours": [{
        "start": "10:00",
        "end": "18:00",
        "dow": "[1]"
    }, {
        "start": "10:00",
        "end": "18:00",
        "dow": "[3]"
    }, {
        "start": "10:00",
        "end": "15:00",
        "dow": "[5]"
    }, {
        "start": "2018-07-28 10:00",
        "end": "2018-07-28 18:00"
    }]
}
```

Only the last array

```
{
    "start": "2018-07-28 10:00",
    "end": "2018-07-28 18:00"
}
```

is not shown in fullcalendar. Is there any other ways to make businessHours for specific date?

Comment: can you please show us your code.. otherwise its very hard to help you! which view do you use? dayview? and do i unserstand you right, that you want the time which is showing only from start to end dynamicaly?

Comment: A google search returned [this result](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3790). **TL;DR;** responses to this Github issue suggest Business hours work only per weekday. You can use [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/) to accomplish this for specific dates as noted by the plugin author.

Comment: businessHours are meant to be a repeating pattern, so in short, no. I agree with Fr0zenFyr, for one-off special cases like your example, use a background event.

Comment: umm... Actually, I set selectConstraint in businessHours. Thus, aren't there any other way to allow select for those specific day except change the businessHours to background event??

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap might help you